# Updating random String every day

Tags: java, android, date, arraylist, random

I have ArrayList with different Strings. I would like to choose one random String from this ArrayList every day and show it in the TextView. I followed the instructions given in this link: [display a random string in textview once a day for java and android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499617/display-a-random-string-in-textview-once-a-day-for-java-and-android-studio) however something is wrong. 
Firstly, I set the initial text in the textView.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firsttask);
    textview.setText("Z1");
```

Then I create 2 dates: CurrentDate always should show given time. dateTime is the date stored in SharedPreferences. At first, CurrentDate and dateTime are the same. Then, the next day the dates are not equaled so the text should be updated and dateTime should be saved so the dates are equal.

```
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String currentDate= df.format(c.getTime());
    String dateTime = df.format(c.getTime());
    saveDate();
    loadDate();
    if(!(dateTime.equals(currentDate))){
        updateList1();
        saveDate();
    }

    public void saveDate (){
    SharedPreferences prefs =     getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_DATE,         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("date", dateTime);
    editor.apply();
    }
    public void loadDate (){
    SharedPreferences prefs =        getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_DATE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    dateTime = prefs.getString("date","default value");
    }

    public void updateList1 (){
    ArrayList<String> task1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    task1.add("t1");
    task1.add("t2");
    task1.add("z3");
    task1.add("z4");
    Random r = new Random();
    task = task1.get(r.nextInt(task1.size()));
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firsttask);
    textview.setText(task);
}
```

This code does not work because after one day, the text is not updated. It still shows "Z1". I am quite new in programming and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt work because when you run this code you firstly run `saveDate();` and then `loadDate();` what will equalize your values. Load first then save and it should work as intended;

Comment: Correct. The code in the Question always saves the current date, failing to first check the saved date.

Comment: Undeniably it was one issue. However, I put saveDate(); and loadDate(); in the correct order and it still did not work. I thought that, beside the date, I had to save the current task too, so I also added task = prefs.getString("text", "default value"); to loadDate(); and editor.putString("text", task); to saveDate(); and the effect was the same: when the date changes, the task updates but when I close the app and reopen it, then the text is "Z1" again. I am not sure if the problem is with saving data, loading them or both.

Comment: Okay, I saved and loaded data properly, I just forgot to set updated text to the TextView. Your answer was correct, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Dochan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640506/642706) is correct: You always save the current date without first loading the saved date for comparison.

## java.time

Also, you are using the troublesome old date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### ISO 8601

When serializing a date-time value as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These formats are sensible, intuitive across human cultures, and unambiguous. For a date-only value, the format is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2016-01-23`.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing & generating strings.

## Revised code

I would move all the logic about updating into a single method, `updateMessageIfNewDay`. Separate out the message selection logic as (a) that may change, and (b) the if-needs-updating code does not need to know where a message comes from nor how the message is selected.

You can detect the JVM’s current default time zone. However, this may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app sharing that JVM. So if the correct date is crucial, ask the user for their intended time zone. For simplicity, here we go with the default zone.

Code below is rough-draft, never tested.

Member variables on the class:

```
LocalDate messageDate ;
String messageContent ;
```

I do not know about Android preferences utility, so I use pseudo-code.

```
void updateMessageIfNewDay() {
    // Determine the current date.
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or use time zone specified by user: ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;

    // Load from storage the date for which we previously displayed a message.
    LocalDate storedMessageDate;
    … if no saved value, leave var null.
        // No code needed here. Leave null.
    … else load string and parse.
        String s = … // load the YYYY-MM-DD string from Android prefs.
        storedMessageDate = LocalDate.parse( s ) ;
    … end if

    // Need to update if:
    // (a) no message stored in prefs, or 
    // (b) No message on this object, so not yet displayed (first encounter in this launch of the app), or
    // (c) stored message is old (not equal to today).
    if( ( null == storedMessageDate ) || 
        ( null = this.messageContent ) || 
        ( ! storedMessageDate.isEqual( today ) ) ) 
    {
            // Update values in memory.
            this.messageDate = today ;
            this.messageContent = this.fetchAnotherMessage();

            // Update values in storage.
            Prefs.save( "messageDate" , this.messageDate.toString() ) ; // pseudo-code
            Prefs.save( "messageContent" , this.messageContent );

            // Update display with contents of this.messageContent.
            … Android UI update code here
     }

}
```

For random choosing, you can use [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) as a convenience rather than track your own `Random` object.

```
private String fetchAnotherMessage() {
    // If called often, save this list as a member on the class, or as a constant. Or if slow-to-load such as database access, save this list.
    // For fast list not called often, don't bother, just instantiate each time.
    int initialCapacity = 4 ;
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity ) ;
    messages.add( "t1" ) ;
    messages.add( "t2" ) ;
    messages.add( "z3" ) ;
    messages.add( "z4" ) ;

    // Choose a random from min to max, both inclusive.
    int min = 1 ;
    int max = messages.size() ;
    int range = ( (max - min) + 1 ) ;     
    int n = ( ( (int)(Math.random() * range) ) + min ) ;
    int index = ( n - 1 ) ; // A `List` is accessed by zero-based index number. So subtract one.
    String message = messages.get( index ) ;
    return message ;
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Thank you for a such extensive answer. It was also helpful.